# All radio button are being checked

Tags: android

All the radio buttons are being checked and I just want the one to be checked when I click the next one its should uncheck the others. Am using recyclerview
How can I be able to uncheck the others when I click the next. ?

Here is my adapter.

```
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by Alex Boey on 8/1/2016.
 */
public class AllAccountsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllAccountsAdapter.ViewHolder> {



    private Context context;

    private List<AllAccount> mList;

    public AllAccountsAdapter(Context context , List<AllAccount> mList){
        this.context = context;
        this.mList =mList;
    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        RadioButton account_no;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            account_no = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.account_no);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_all_account ,parent , false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      final AllAccount list=mList.get(position);
      holder.account_no.setText(list.getAccountNumber());
        holder.account_no.setChecked(false);

      holder.account_no.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

              if(context instanceof MyAccount){
                  ((MyAccount)context).onRefresh(list.getAccountNumber());
              }
          }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }


}
```

and this is my item xml with one radio button which am using.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/clickable"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton
            android:textColor="@color/theme_color_primary_dark"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/account_no"
            android:text="@string/accept"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        </RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>



    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tired to include the recycler viewer with a `<RadioGroup>` and remove the `<RadioGroup>` from the `CardView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because each card view is defining its own radiogroup. There is no native support for radio groups across cardviews, you will have to manually uncheck other views when any of them is checked, or you can try to put the whole cardview list thing inside a radio group